# VisionTek Flashdrive issue with mounting

Tags: partitioning, usb, hard-drive

I got a visionTek USB 3.0 128 GB drive. https://www.visiontek.com/solid-state-drives/128gb-usb-3-0-pocket-ssd-detail.html

It won't mount on Ubuntu 14.04. It does show up in `lsusb` as ASMedia SATA bridge.

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 004 Device 051: ID 17ef:600e Lenovo 
Bus 004 Device 044: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 040: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. ASMedia 2105 SATA bridge
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Screenshot of `gnome-disks`
[image]

```
$ ls /dev/sd*
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sda4  /dev/sda6  /dev/sda8
/dev/sda1  /dev/sda3  /dev/sda5  /dev/sda7  /dev/sdb
```

`/dev/sdb` is listed. But `fdisk -l` does not work with it.

```
$ fdisk -l /dev/sdb 
Cannot open /dev/sdb
```

$ dmesg -T #just after plugging the device

```
[Wed Feb  3 09:54:49 2016] usb 3-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 41 using ehci-pci
[Wed Feb  3 09:54:50 2016] usb 3-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa
[Wed Feb  3 09:54:50 2016] usb 3-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[Wed Feb  3 09:54:50 2016] usb 3-1.2: Product: SSD USB 3.0
[Wed Feb  3 09:54:50 2016] usb 3-1.2: Manufacturer: VT
[Wed Feb  3 09:54:50 2016] usb 3-1.2: SerialNumber: 000000000007
[Wed Feb  3 09:54:50 2016] usb-storage 3-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[Wed Feb  3 09:54:50 2016] usb-storage 3-1.2:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 55aa: 400000
[Wed Feb  3 09:54:50 2016] scsi host38: usb-storage 3-1.2:1.0
[Wed Feb  3 09:54:51 2016] scsi 38:0:0:0: Direct-Access     VT       SSD USB 3.0      0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[Wed Feb  3 09:54:51 2016] sd 38:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[Wed Feb  3 09:54:51 2016] sd 38:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I should I get the device working. Also `gparted` does not show `/dev/sdb`?

Comment: Just after you plug the USB key in, do `dmesg -T` to see what the system thinks about the drive. Also look at `/var/log/kern.log`. These places are where Linux logs its actions and decisions to mount or complain about your USB SSD.

Comment: Just posted `dmesg -T`. However, I don't have `/var/log/kern.log` on my system.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`

Comment: I do not wish to upgrade. Will try linux-firmware-nonfree

Comment: still does not help.

Comment: Try `sudo fdisk -l`, which will list all your disk devices.  `sudo apt-get update` updates the list of available  packages. `sudo apt-get upgrade` brings your system up to date with bug fixes from the updated list of packages. The release upgrade you seem to want avoid is invoked by `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. Read `man apt-get`.  `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` is how people keep their 14.04 (and other Debian/Ubuntu systems) up-to-date with bug fixes.

Comment: `sudo fdisk -l` lists my partition for sda. However nothing for sdb

Comment: Not having `/var/log/kern.log` indicates a major problem with your system. Is `rsyslogd` running? (`pgrep rsyslogd`, `sudo service rsyslog status`). To start `rsyslog` once `sudo service rsyslog start` . Not having `rsyslogd` running means that you don't have access to all sorts of diagnostic information!

Comment: `rsyslogd` is running. I am using ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I am sorry, I do have /var/log/kern.log.

Comment: Does the drive work in other USB ports (e. g. USB 2.0), other operating systems or on other computers?

Comment: Does not work. I thinking on contacting visionTek for warranty.

Comment: @waltinator IIRC, `dist-upgrade` doesn't actually do a distribution upgrade as much as it just does "smart" package resolution (installs/uninstalls packages to resolve all dependencies).

Answer (score 0):

This flash drive seems to show all the signs of not working, and will probably never work.

Typically, flash drives will always present a disk of some sort: either formatted, or an "Unallocated" partition type. If neither of these exist, it means that the drive is refusing to expose a workable filesystem or block storage device. If there was any underlying block device, `fdisk` would have been able to detect it (unless you weren't root?). This by itself *heavily* implies a hardware or firmware failure on the part of your drive.

Your best course of action would be to contact your drive's manufacturer and request a replacement.